# jackson tree mapper match key value per path(key="key1")

Tags: java, json, jackson

Does jackson tree mapper allow matching keyvalues similar to xpath?  I have a generic list that comes back and want to match the key="key" then get a value at that same level as the key?

json:

```
[
   {
      "key":"value1",
      "values":[
         10.5
      ]
   },
   {
      "key":"value2",
      "values":[
         20.5
      ]
   }
   o o o more values here... o o o
]
```

code:

```
 JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(thejsonfromabove);
 //How can I do something like this?
 //  ... match the key = value1 and the the values within?  psdeudo code below...
 int whatever = rootNode.path(?).path("key"=="value1").path(0).getIntValue();  // Get 10.5
```

Is there something similar to xpath when matching nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Json-path](http://code.google.com/p/json-path/) for this purpose. See the examples in that page.

I am not sure jackson supports a similar feature.